# Launch console application in iTerm on boot

Tags: macos, iterm

How can I launch some command (console application) in iTerm2 on system boot? There should be only one instance of this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script which will run Your app. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/executable
```

Save it, change this to be executable with `chmod +x` in **Terminal** or **iTerm2** app. Right click on this file and choose **Get Info**, select the prefered app which will open it (in Your case **iTerm2** app). Open Preferences.app, go to **Users and Groups** -> **Login** and add Your script there. With this once You login Your script will be opened in **iTerm2** app.